# How to fetch values using Permutation Feature Importance

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-mining, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I have a dataset with 5K (and 60 features) records focused on binary classification.

Please note that this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47111434/randomforestregressor-and-feature-importances-error) doesn't work here

I am trying to generate feature importance using `Permutation Feature Importance`. However, I get the below error. Can you please look at my code and let me know whether I am making any mistake?

```
import eli5
from eli5.sklearn import PermutationImportance
logreg =LogisticRegression()
model = logreg.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
perm = PermutationImportance(model, random_state=1)
eli5.show_weights(perm, feature_names = X.columns.tolist())
```

I get an error like as shown below

```
AttributeError: 'PermutationImportance' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'
```

Can you help me resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at your attributes of PermutationImportance object via

```
ord(perm)
```

you can see all attributes and methods **BUT** after you fit your PI object, meaning that you need to do:

```
perm = PermutationImportance(model, random_state=1).fit(X_train,y)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if I do `ord(perm)`, I get the below error `TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but PermutationImportance found`. Upvoted anyway for the response

Comment: I had the same issue and I can confirm that the answer given works: we need to fit the PermutationImportance object so that the feature importances becomes available. You can fit the PI object with training data but may also use test data for generalization.
From the documentation:
"You can call PermutationImportance.fit either with training data, or with a held-out dataset (in the latter case feature_importances_ would be importances of features for generalization)." Source: https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodocs/sklearn.html#module-eli5.sklearn.permutation_importance